# Clase con un mismo tipo de Exception pero diferentes mensajes de error

Tags: java, excepciones

En un fichero llamado Team.java tengo lo siguiente (solo enseño parte del código):

```
public class Team{

private static final String MSG_ERR_ENERGY_RANGE_VALUE = "[ERROR] Team's energy cannot negative either greater than 100!!";
private static final String MSG_ERR_HEIGHT_VALUE = "[ERROR]: Team's height cannot negative either 0!!";
..........
public void setEnergy(int energy) throws Exception {
    if(energy<0 || energy>100) throw new Exception(MSG_ERR_ENERGY_RANGE_VALUE);
..........
public void setHeight(double height) throws Exception{
    if(height<=0) {
        throw new Exception(MSG_ERR_HEIGHT_VALUE);
..........
```

Tengo que crear una clase llamada TeamException que hereda de Exception. El código es el siguiente:

```
public class TeamException extends Exception{

public TeamException() {
    super();
}

public TeamException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
}
}
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es trasladar los atributos de tipo String que contienen los mensajes de excepción del fichero Team.java al fichero TeamException.java. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un atributo de mensaje en la clase `TeamException` y sobreescribe el método `getMessage()`, el código debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
public class TeamException extends Exception {

    private String message;

    public TeamException() {

    }

    public TeamException(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿En el fichero Team.java tengo que hacer algo, o lo dejo tal cual?

Comment: Si capturas la excepción mediante un bloque try-catch, puedes utilizar el mensaje personalizado. Sino, se queda tal cual.

Comment: Gracias José María.